# C# Uploading image to Cheverto's upload.php

Tags: c#, visual-studio, upload

I have a C# application that takes screenshots and creates image files. I can't seem to find out how I would create an uploading method that the file path would be passed into using cheverto's upload.php. Cheverto is just an image gallery system.

Here is there API: https://chevereto.com/docs/api-v1

Here is the upload.php stored on my server: https://pastebin.com/bU4EJAVx

```
<?php

namespace CHV;
use G, Exception;

class Upload {
// filename => name.ext
// file => /full/path/to/name.ext
// name => name

public $source;
public $uploaded;

// Sets the type of resource being uploaded
public function setType($type) {
    $this->type = $type;
}

// Set source
public function setSource($source) {
    $this->source = $source;
    $this->type = G\is_url($this->source) ? 'url' : 'file';
}

// Set destination
public function setDestination($destination) {
    $this->destination = G\forward_slash($destination);
}

// Set storage
public function setStorageId($storage_id) {
    $this->storage_id = is_numeric($storage_id) ? $storage_id : NULL;
}

// Set file basename
public function setFilename($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
}

// Set options
public function setOptions($options) {
    $this->options = $options;
}

// Set individual option
public function setOption($key, $value) {
    $this->options[$key] = $value;
}

// Default options
public static function getDefaultOptions() {
    return array(
        'max_size'          => G\get_bytes('2 MB'), // it should be 'max_filesize'
        'filenaming'        => 'original',
        'exif'              => TRUE,
        'allowed_formats'   => self::getAvailableImageFormats(), // array
    );
}

/**
 * Do the thing
 * @Exeption 4xx
 */
public function exec() {

    // Merge options
    $this->options = array_merge(self::getDefaultOptions(), (array) $this->options);

    $this->validateInput(); // Exception 1

    $this->fetchSource(); // Exception 2

    $this->validateSourceFile(); // Exception 3

    if(!is_array($this->options['allowed_formats'])) {
        $this->options['allowed_formats'] = explode(',', $this->options['allowed_formats']);
    }

    // Save the source name
    $this->source_name = G\get_filename_without_extension($this->type == "url" ? $this->source : $this->source["name"]);

    // Set file extension
    $this->extension = $this->source_image_fileinfo["extension"];

    // Workaround the $name
    if(!$this->name) {
        $this->name = $this->source_name;
    }

    // Fix conflicting starting dots (some Apache installs)
    $this->name = ltrim($this->name, '.');

    // Fix file extension
    if(G\get_file_extension($this->name) == $this->extension) {
        $this->name = G\get_filename_without_extension($this->name);
    }

    // Set the fixed filename
    $this->fixed_filename = preg_replace('/(.*)\.(th|md|original|lg)\.([\w]+)$/', '$1.$3', $this->name . '.' . $this->extension);

    // Workaround for JPEG Exif data
    if($this->extension == 'jpg' and array_key_exists('exif', $this->options)) {
        $this->source_image_exif = NULL;
        if($this->options['exif']) {
            // Fetch JPEG Exif data (when available)
            if(function_exists('exif_read_data')) {
                $this->source_image_exif = @exif_read_data($this->downstream);
                if($this->source_image_exif) {
                    $this->source_image_exif['FileName'] = $this->source_filename;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Remove JPEG Exif data
            $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->downstream);
            if($img) {
                imagejpeg($img, $this->downstream, 90);
                imagedestroy($img);
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Set uploaded_file
     * Local storage uploads will be allocated at the target destination
     * External storage will be allocated to the temp directory
     */
    $this->uploaded_file = G\name_unique_file($this->destination, $this->options['filenaming'], $this->fixed_filename);

    $this->source = [
        'filename'      => $this->source_filename, // file.ext
        'name'          => $this->source_name, // file
        'image_exif'    => $this->source_image_exif, // exif-data array
        'fileinfo'      => G\get_image_fileinfo($this->downstream), // fileinfo array
    ];

    // Fix image orientation
    if($this->source_image_exif and $this->source_image_exif["Orientation"]) {
        $this->fixImageOrientation($this->downstream, $this->source_image_exif);
    }

    $uploaded = @rename($this->downstream, $this->uploaded_file);
    @unlink($this->downstream);

    if(file_exists($this->downstream)) {
        error_log("Warning: temp file " . $this->downstream . "wasn't removed.");
    }

    if(!$uploaded) {
        throw new UploadException("Can't move temp file to its destination", 400);
    }

    // For some PHP environments
    if(!$this->storage_id) {
        @chmod($this->uploaded_file, 0644);
    }

    $this->uploaded = array(
        'file'      => $this->uploaded_file,
        'filename'  => G\get_filename($this->uploaded_file),
        'name'      => G\get_filename_without_extension($this->uploaded_file),
        'fileinfo'  => G\get_image_fileinfo($this->uploaded_file)
    );

}

// Get available (supported) extensions
public static function getAvailableImageFormats() {
    $formats = Settings::get('upload_available_image_formats');
    return explode(',', $formats);
}

// Failover since v3.8.12
public static function getEnabledImageFormats() {
    return Image::getEnabledImageFormats();
}

/**
 * validate_input aka "first stage validation"
 * This checks for valid input source data
 * @Exception 1XX
 */
protected function validateInput() {

    $check_missing = ["type", "source", "destination"];
    missing_values_to_exception($this, "CHV\UploadException", $check_missing, 100);

    // Validate $type
    if(!preg_match("/^(url|file)$/", $this->type)) {
        throw new UploadException('Invalid $type "'.$this->type.'"', 110);
    }

    // Handle flood
    $flood = self::handleFlood();
    if($flood) {
        throw new UploadException(strtr('Flood detected. You can only upload %limit% images per %time%', ['%limit%' => $flood['limit'], '%time%' => $flood['by']]), 130);
    }

    // Validate $source
    if($this->type == 'file') {
        if(count($this->source) < 5) { // Valid $_FILES ?
            throw new UploadException("Invalid file source", 120);
        }
    } else if($this->type == "url") {
        if(!G\is_image_url($this->source) && !G\is_url($this->source)) {
            throw new UploadException("Invalid image URL", 122);
        }
    }

    // Validate $destination
    if(!is_dir($this->destination)) { // Try to create the missing directory

        $base_dir = G\add_ending_slash(G_ROOT_PATH . explode('/', preg_replace('#'.G_ROOT_PATH.'#', '', $this->destination, 1))[0]);
        $base_perms = fileperms($base_dir);

        $old_umask = umask(0);
        $make_destination = mkdir($this->destination, $base_perms, true);
        chmod($this->destination, $base_perms);
        umask($old_umask);

        if(!$make_destination) {
            throw new UploadException('$destination '.$this->destination.' is not a dir', 130);
        }

    }

    // Can read $destination dir?
    if(!is_readable($this->destination)) {
        throw new UploadException("Can't read target destination dir", 131);
    }

    // Can write $destination dir?
    if(!is_writable($this->destination)) {
        throw new UploadException("Can't write target destination dir", 132);
    }

    // Fix $destination trailing
    $this->destination = G\add_ending_slash($this->destination);

}

/**
 * Fetch the $source file
 * @Exception 2XX
 */
protected function fetchSource() {

    // Set the downstream file      
    $this->downstream = @tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'chvtemp');

    if(!$this->downstream || !@is_writable($this->downstream)) {
        $this->downstream = @tempnam($this->destination, 'chvtemp');
        if(!$this->downstream) {
            throw new UploadException("Can't get a tempnam", 200);
        }
    }

    if($this->type == 'file') {

        if($this->source['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

            switch($this->source['error']) {
                case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE: // 1
                    throw new UploadException('File too big', 201);
                break;
                case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE: // 2
                    throw new UploadException('File exceeds form max size', 201);
                break;
                case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL: // 3
                    throw new UploadException('File was partially uploaded', 201);
                break;
                case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE: // 4
                    throw new UploadException('No file was uploaded', 201);
                break;
                case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR: // 5
                    throw new UploadException('Missing temp folder', 201);
                break;
                case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE: // 6
                    throw new UploadException('System write error', 201);
                break;
                case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION: // 7
                    throw new UploadException('The upload was stopped', 201);
                break;
            }

        }

        if(!@rename($this->source['tmp_name'], $this->downstream)) {
            throw new UploadException("Can't move temp file to the target upload dir", 203);
        }

    } else if($this->type == "url") {
        try {
            G\fetch_url($this->source, $this->downstream);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            throw new UploadException($e->getMessage(), 202);
        }
    }

    $this->source_filename = basename($this->type == "file" ? $this->source["name"] : $this->source);

}

protected function fixImageOrientation($image_filename, $exif) {
    if($exif['Orientation'] == 1) return;
    switch($this->extension) {
        case 'jpg':
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_filename);
        break;
    }
    switch($exif['Orientation']) {
        case 3:
            $image = imagerotate($image, 180, 0);
        break;
        case 6:
            $image = imagerotate($image, -90, 0);
        break;
        case 8:
            $image = imagerotate($image, 90, 0);
        break;
    }
    imagejpeg($image, $image_filename, 90);
}

/**
 * validate_source_file aka "second stage validation"
 * This checks for valid input source data
 * @Exception 3XX
 */
protected function validateSourceFile() {

    // Nothing to do here
    if(!file_exists($this->downstream)) {
        throw new UploadException("Can't fetch target upload source (downstream)", 300);
    }

    $this->source_image_fileinfo = G\get_image_fileinfo($this->downstream);

    // file info?
    if(!$this->source_image_fileinfo) {
        throw new UploadException("Can't get target upload source info", 310);
    }

    // Valid image fileinto?
    if($this->source_image_fileinfo['width'] == '' || $this->source_image_fileinfo['height'] == '') {
        throw new UploadException("Invalid image", 311);
    }

    // Available image format?
    if(!in_array($this->source_image_fileinfo['extension'], self::getAvailableImageFormats())) {
        throw new UploadException("Unavailable image format", 313);
    }

    // Enabled image format?
    if(!in_array($this->source_image_fileinfo['extension'], $this->options['allowed_formats'])) {
        throw new UploadException(sprintf("Disabled image format (%s)", $this->source_image_fileinfo['extension']), 314);
    }

    // Mime
    if(!$this->isValidImageMime($this->source_image_fileinfo["mime"])) {
        throw new UploadException("Invalid image mimetype", 312);
    }

    // Size
    if(!$this->options['max_size']) {
        $this->options['max_size'] = self::getDefaultOptions()['max_size'];
    }
    if($this->source_image_fileinfo["size"] > $this->options["max_size"]) {
        throw new UploadException("File too big - max " . G\format_bytes($this->options["max_size"]), 313);
    }

    // BMP?
    if($this->source_image_fileinfo['extension'] == 'bmp') {
        $this->ImageConvert = new ImageConvert($this->downstream, "png", $this->downstream);
        $this->downstream = $this->ImageConvert->out;
        $this->source_image_fileinfo = G\get_image_fileinfo($this->downstream);
    }

}

// Handle flood uploads
protected static function handleFlood() {

    $logged_user = Login::getUser();

    if(!getSetting('flood_uploads_protection') || $logged_user['is_admin']) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $flood_limit = [];
    foreach(['minute', 'hour', 'day', 'week', 'month'] as $v) {
        $flood_limit[$v] = getSetting('flood_uploads_' . $v);
    }

    try {
        $db = DB::getInstance();
        $flood_db = $db->queryFetchSingle(
        "SELECT
            COUNT(IF(image_date_gmt >= DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE), 1, NULL)) AS minute,
            COUNT(IF(image_date_gmt >= DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR), 1, NULL)) AS hour,
            COUNT(IF(image_date_gmt >= DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), 1, NULL)) AS day,
            COUNT(IF(image_date_gmt >= DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK), 1, NULL)) AS week,
            COUNT(IF(image_date_gmt >= DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), 1, NULL)) AS month
        FROM ".DB::getTable('images')." WHERE image_uploader_ip='".G\get_client_ip()."' AND image_date_gmt >= DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)");
    } catch(Exception $e) {} // Silence

    $is_flood = FALSE;
    $flood_by = '';
    foreach(['minute', 'hour', 'day', 'week', 'month'] as $v) {
        if($flood_limit[$v] > 0 and $flood_db[$v] >= $flood_limit[$v]) {
            $flood_by = $v;
            $is_flood = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }

    if($is_flood) {
        if(getSetting('flood_uploads_notify') and !$_SESSION['flood_uploads_notify'][$flood_by]) {
            try {
                $message = strtr('Flooding IP <a href="'.G\get_base_url('search/images/?q=ip:%ip').'">%ip</a>', ['%ip' => G\get_client_ip()]) . '<br>';
                if($logged_user) {
                    $message .= 'User <a href="'.$logged_user['url'].'">'.$logged_user['name'].'</a><br>';
                }
                $message .= '<br>';
                $message .= '<b>Uploads per time period</b>'."<br>";
                $message .= 'Minute: '.$flood_db['minute']."<br>";
                $message .= 'Hour: '.$flood_db['hour']."<br>";
                $message .= 'Week: '.$flood_db['day']."<br>";
                $message .= 'Month: '.$flood_db['week']."<br>";
                system_notification_email(['subject' => 'Flood report IP '. G\get_client_ip(), 'message' => $message]);
                $_SESSION['flood_uploads_notify'][$flood_by] = true;
            } catch(Exception $e) {} // Silence
        }

        return ['flood' => TRUE, 'limit' => $flood_limit[$flood_by], 'count' => $flood_db[$flood_by], 'by' => $flood_by];
    }

    return FALSE;
}

protected function isValidImageMime($mime) {
    return preg_match("@image/(gif|pjpeg|jpeg|png|x-png|bmp|x-ms-bmp|x-windows-bmp)$@", $mime);
}

protected function isValidNamingOption($string) {
    return in_array($string, array("mixed", "random", "original"));
}
}

class UploadException extends Exception {}
```

Thank you for any help or guidance!

Comment: Is this meant to be tagged c#? The code is all PHP.

Comment: I'm looking for help on creating C# code that would connect to this php code.

Comment: I think no one wants to read 5 pages of PHP to determine what input your program accepts, just to help you write a C# program that you haven't started.  Simplify and clarify your question, and it may get more traction.

Comment: $this->uploaded_file = G\name_unique_file($this->destination, $this->options['filenaming'], $this->fixed_filename);
 This is on line 142, it looks like I should just pass in my variables into this?

Comment: This topic was the same issue, the figured it out but never fully corrected it on the post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27052235/upload-image-to-a-chevereto-website-c-sharp